# Code Igniter: как использовать .htaccess

Tags: redirect, .htaccess, php, codeigniter

Здравствуйте, возник такой вопрос. Мне нужно сделать редирект на сайте (сайт на CI), с помощью .htaccess. Во-первых, проблема такая: .htaccess работает не так, как нужно (редиректишь на http://site.ru, сначала грузится сам сайт, а потом уже редирект на указанную ссылку, в итоге получается: http://first-site.ru/site.ru/ вместо http://site.ru), во-вторых, как сделать что бы по умолчанию класс грузился не на основной сайт (url), вида http://site.ru, а именно создавался url с классом: http://site.ru/class/.

Подскажите, как решить

Comment: у код-игнайтера есть свой достаточный механизм переадресаций, зачем туда еще .хтакцевв тулить?..

Answer (score 1):

Codeigniter тут не при чём, в смысле в codeigniter нету особенного .htaccess. Грубо говоря .htaccess  - это "конфиг" через которы можно "действовать" на сервер http://xpoint.ru/forums/internet/webservers/apache/thread/40177.xhtml там проде всё понятно

Вот ещё, для изучения  http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=29&id=1364